Discrepancy in exponentiation and eigenvalue computation for positive semidefinite matrices with large norm
I am doing some computations with Hermitian (complex) positive semidefinite matrices. The computation involve taking their exponents. The exponent (with base 2) of a matrix A, which I shall denote as 2^A can be obtained by applying the exponentiation function to the eigenvalues.
Thus each eigenvalue of 2^A must be 2**(eigenvalue of A). However, there seems to be a discrepancy for matrices with large norm (trace norm/nuclear norm >= 60) when I implement this in numpy/scipy. As in, these two sets of eigenvalues do not agree, and the Euclidean distance between these two vectors of eigenvalues can be quite large, and it grows as the A becomes larger (measured in terms of trace norm).
Here is my code
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg as sla

d = 2
X = np.random.randn(d, d) + 1j*(np.random.randn(d, d))  # Generate an arbitrary complex matrix
P = X@X.conj().T                         # Multiply by its transpose to obtain PSD matrix
P = P/np.trace(P)                        # Normalise to obtain density matrix (PSD matrix with unit trace)

for t in range(20, 75, 5):
  Q = t*P                                 # Scaling the matrix
  D, V = sla.eigh(Q)                      # Eigendecomposition 
  M = V @ np.diag(2**D) @ V.conj().T      # Constructing M = 2**Q

  #Comparing the eigenvalues of M vs 2**(EigVals(Q)). This should be equal.
  print(t, norm(sla.eigvalsh(M) - 2**sla.eigvalsh(Q))) 

And here is the output for a random intialization of X.
The first column is t which is the trace norm and second column is the euclidean distance between the
vector of eigenvalues using the two methods.
20 3.654601116809922e-12
25 6.374134689249895e-11
30 9.33093987260751e-10
35 3.728611604386753e-09
40 5.962181140973812e-08
45 9.573880441485143e-07
50 1.4168248818502024e-05
55 4.866518429480493e-05
60 0.0024326798970430987
65 0.025923866144586645
70 0.12695862169940617

The discrepancy grows with t. What could be the reason? Is there a mistake in my implementation?

Your implementation is correct. However when comparing arrays with large norm, you should consider normalizing the result. It cannot be better than machine_precision * norm(a)
If you replace the last line with print(t, sla.norm(sla.eigvalsh(M) - 2**sla.eigvalsh(Q)) / sla.norm(M)), you see your results stay correct up to machine precision
EDIT: fix sla import name
